# index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I get this error when I run the application.

```
 Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444
```

I pull data from firebase and upload it to MapKit in UITableViewCell. It was working on my friend's computer but when I run it again on my own computer, I got this error. How can I solve this problem?

ViewController:

```
     import UIKit
     import Firebase
     import SDWebImage
     import MapKit
     import CoreLocation


    class anasayfaViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var UserNameArray = [String]()
    var UserCommentArray = [String]()
    var UserImageArray = [String]()
    var DocumentIDarray = [String]()
    var UserLocationArray = [GeoPoint]()
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return UserNameArray.count
    }
    
    /*
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
     */
    
   
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCell
        
        let username = UserNameArray[indexPath.row]
        let comment = UserCommentArray[indexPath.row]
        let imageURL = UserImageArray[indexPath.row]
        let location = UserLocationArray[indexPath.row]. ------ (Error Line )
        
        cell.prepare(username: username, imageURL: imageURL, comment: comment, location: location)
       
        return cell 
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        //tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
       
         getdataFromFirestore()
    }
    
    
    func getdataFromFirestore(){
        let firestoreDatabase = Firestore.firestore()
        
        firestoreDatabase.collection("Posts").order(by: "Date", descending: true).addSnapshotListener { [weak self] (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            
            if snapshot?.isEmpty != true {
                
                self?.UserCommentArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                self?.UserNameArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                self?.UserImageArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                self?.documentIDarray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                self?.UserLocationArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                
                
                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    let documentID = document.documentID
                    self?.documentIDarray.append(documentID)
                    
                    if let sharedBy = document.get("SharedBy") as? String {
                        self?.UserNameArray.append(sharedBy)
                    }
                    
                    if let sharedComment = document.get("SharedComment") as? String {
                        self?.UserCommentArray.append(sharedComment)
                    }
                    
                    if let sharedUrl = document.get("imageUrl") as? String {
                        self?.UserImageArray.append(sharedUrl)
                        
                    }
                    
                    if let sharedLocation = document.get("Location") as? GeoPoint {
                        self?.UserLocationArray.append(sharedLocation)
                    }
                }
                
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }}
}
```

Comment: You might have a problem with converting your data to GeoPoint.

Comment: Your problem is that you conditionally append to the arrays, so in the case where the conditional unwrap of an item (such as a geopoint) fails you end up with a different number of elements in the arrays. Having multiple arrays for related data is nearly always a code smell. Have a single array of a suitable struct and access the properties that way.  You will still need to device what to do when an unwrap fails; provide a default value? Discard the entire record?